# How to restrict user to enter digits or special charater or blank or space in JTextField in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a project in Java Swing. Now there is a text field for user name. I want to validate that text field so that user **can't enter digits or special character or blank or space**. In short I want a restriction such that user can't enter anything other than alphabets. The database is MS Access and table name is "test" and there is only one column named "sname". As I am a beginner, simpler techniques will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Ex_test extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Ex_test ob=new Ex_test();
    }
    JTextField tf1;
    JButton b1;
    int num1;
    public Ex_test()
    {
    super("test");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    tf1=new JTextField(20);
    add(tf1);

    b1=new JButton("ok");
    add(b1);

    setSize(500,500);
    setVisible(true);

    b1.addActionListener(this);

    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        if (ae.getActionCommand()=="ok")
        {   
            try
            {   
                String str=tf1.getText();
                Connection con;
                PreparedStatement ps;
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:test");
                ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into test values('"+str+"')");
                ps.executeUpdate();
                con.close();
                ps.close();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"DATA SUBMITTED SUCCESSFULLY.");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Exception Occurred.");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this - i used regex which validates input from user, more about regex you will find here : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

```
try
        {   
            String str=tf1.getText();
            if ( !(str.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))) {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please insert only characters.");
                  tf1.setText("");
            }else{

            Connection con;
            PreparedStatement ps;
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:test");
            ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into test values('"+str+"')");
            ps.executeUpdate();
            con.close();
            ps.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"DATA SUBMITTED SUCCESSFULLY.");}
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Exception Occurred.");
        }
```

Comment: `In short I want a restriction such that user can't enter anything other than alphabets.` - then you should be using a `JFormattedTextField` or a `DocumentFilter`, which will prevent the typed character from being entered into the text field. This approach does the edit AFTER the character has already been entered, which means the user will now have to delete the character.

Comment: tf1.setText(""); - program will do it for user

Comment: Why would you want to use setText()? What if the user enters "abcd1efg". Only one character is wrong. You should not force the user to re-enter the entire text.

Answer (score 1):

Use a JFormattedTextField. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) for more information and examples.

You can use a `MaskFormatter` to specify that you only want to allow alphabetic characters.